# Only show an org habit on the agenda a few days into the future

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, org-habit

How can I set up an org habit that repeats 10 days after completion, but only shows up on the agenda if the next instance is less than 6 days away?

An equivalent way of expressing the same thing: a habit that repeats every 10 days, but does not show up until 4 days after the last completion.

Answer (score 3):

Try doing a scheduled time stamp of: `SCHEDULED: <2015-11-18 Wed .+10d/13d -6d>`.  The trailing `-6d` says to only start showing it in the agenda when you're 6 days away from the date.

Comment: I didn't know about that syntax, thank you! Is there a org habit reference somewhere? Unfortunately it does not work as advertised. It still appears in the agenda, just six days later (2015-11-24), and consequently is marked `Sched. 7x`. Can I hide it from the agenda entirely until (scheduled date - today < 6 days)?

Comment: I believe I may have misunderstood org agenda semantics. I see now that this habit should probably be `DEADLINE` instead of `SCHEDULE`, with `.+10d --6d`, and that tasks should not be started until they are on the current day's agenda.

Comment: So you would probably want `SCHEDULED: <2015-11-18 Wed .+10d/13d -6d>` as the `--` will make it only affect the first time.  There's documentation on the `SCHEDULED` and `DEADLINE` timestamp format here: http://orgmode.org/manual/Deadlines-and-scheduling.html